# Rails CSV Export - leading zeros are ignored by CSV reader

Tags: excel, csv, ruby-on-rails-3.2, export-to-csv

I have code that creates a `csv` for address.

The problem is that the zipcodes that have a `leading zero` are exported properly, but when the `csv` is open in `Excel`, the `leading zero` on zipcodes is `removed`.

```
addresses = [["123 Street", "New York", "0123", "USA"], ["421 Street", "New York", "0233", "USA"]]
CSV.open(csv_file, "w", force_quotes: true) do |csv|
  csv << [street_address, city, zipcode, state]
  addresses.each do |address|
    csv << address
  end
end
```

Is there a way to export a number as a string from a csv, which can be read by excel reader without removing leading zeros?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `=""` to your exported field:

```
"123 Street","New York",="0123","USA"
```

This should preserve the leading zero's in Excel.

Comment: Yes, this will work. but if I use same CSV somewhere else to import address it will import zipcode with `=` sign.

Comment: @Sampat - Yes, it's a _hack_ for Excel. So either Excel should be fixed, or we could hope that a decent parser recognizes this.